# Why in practice in php frameworks, databases are not considered to be created by migrations?

Tags: php, migration, database-migration

I am using Laravel framework mostly for my php development. I've looked at many tutorials and be participated in couple of php projects. I haven't encountered with the case in which the database creation is defined in a migration. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Laravel does provide mechanisms for creating the schema: http://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly - but creating a database is a one time act, while migrations are run whenever the database structure changes, with the details recorded in the database itself; and you wouldn't recreate the database whenever you ran a migration

Comment: The good thing about having database creation as a first migration, I think, is that you can copy all the migrations, put it in a new machine and it takes care of all database tasks, and you don't need to worry about creating database on your new server.

Comment: Then perhaps you should suggest it to framework creators, although often a database is created along with the user accounts to access it, so the creation itself is created from a different user account